# Using POST data in array_diff with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, post

**What I'm trying to do:**

treat the POST data from a multi-select input with the array_diff() function

**Initial code:**

```
$relations_to_delete=array_diff($selectedEnjeuxMetiers,$this->request->data['EnjeuxMembership']['EnjeuxMetier']);
```

**Probem:** It was not working when nothing was selected in the multiselect input

**Current solution:**

```
  if(!empty($this->request->data['EnjeuxMembership']['EnjeuxMetier'])){
        $relations_to_delete=array_diff($selectedEnjeuxMetiers,$this->request->data['EnjeuxMembership']['EnjeuxMetier']);
                                                         
   }else{
            $relations_to_delete=$selectedEnjeuxMetiers;
   }
```

This solution works. !=null was not working, nor gettype()=="array"

**Question:** Could anyone could explain why the if(!empty()) test is necessary, and if the problem comes from the  POST data or the array_diff function?

EDIT: It works with gettype()=="array". The problem was that the type when there is no data is not an empty array but an empty string.

**Additional info:** [CakePHP docs about the way Post data are converted to an array.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#request-handling)

Comment: Give a var_dump on the value and tell us the value returned

Comment: It returns ''    So it's an empty string.

Comment: Ok solved. It works with gettype()==array. Must have made a typo the first time.

Comment: var_dump("" != null) return false the correct is var_dump("" !=== null) about the array, use is_array function.

Comment: Thanks Fabiano. Copy this comment and I will accept.

Comment: ... Didn't see you made the other answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the function "empty()", the variable is considered empty if it is equal to:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

The value should be coming "" or NULL when no option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the type when there is no data is not an empty array but an empty string.